# Mocha says that assert.equal([0, 0], [0, 0]) fails. Why?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I am testing with mocha, some module with some behavior. For example I want that

```
var module = new Module()
module.getSomething()
```

will returns [0,0]. So, I'd tried to test it:

```
var assert = require('assert')
  , Module = require('../lib/module')
describe('Module()', function () {
    describe('#getSomething()', function () {
        it('should return [0,0] by default', function () {
            var map = new Module()
            assert.equal([0, 0], map.getCenter()[0])
        })
    })
})
```

Test fails. After some tries, ... I fall into this test:

```
var assert = require('assert')
describe('[0,0]', function () {
    it('should be equals to [0,0]', function () {
        assert.equal([0, 0], [0, 0])
    })
})
```

Mmmm I think I have some gap in javascript. Well, .. I need to create a module that at some point returns little objects like {x:0,y:0}. Can someone explain me the way to test this stuff? This way works, ... is correct?

```
describe('#getCenter()', function () {
    it('should return [0,0] by default', function () {
        var map = new Map()
        assert.equal(0, map.getCenter().x)
        assert.equal(0, map.getCenter().y)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply because, in JavaScript, comparison of objects is done by reference and not by deep equality check.

Examples :

```
[] == [] // false
[1] == [1] // false
({} === {}) // false
```

Instead, you can use `assert.deepEqual`, which will do what you expect.

(just in case you're wondering, I put the parenthesis around `{}` to make it an expression, instead of making the first `{}` a block (code would be `{}; === {}` thus invalid))